# How to display a dropdown select based on the value of other dropdown select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Suppose I have a dropdown select option like below:

```
 <form>
    <select name="option" >
                <option value="">Select a Value:</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>

    </select>
</form>
```

When any user Selects the Option 1 I want to display the following dropdown select beside it instantly

```
 <select name="name" >
                <option value="">Select a person:</option>
                <option value="john">john</option>
                <option value="Micheal">Micheal</option>

    </select>
```

Or, if any user Selects the Option 2 I want to display the following dropdown select beside it instantly

```
 <select name="class" >
                <option value="">Select a person:</option>
                <option value="Class 1">Class 1</option>
                <option value="Class 2">Class 2</option>

    </select>
```

Would you please kindly show me how to do this?
I am using Codeigniter.

Comment: The two possible select menus, are they dynamic or static? If static, the answers will do, otherwise I guess you have to write your own functions. But still take the answers as a point to start from

Comment: You can also use the cascadeFrom functionality.  Here is an example of it.    http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function(){
    $('.hidden').hide();
    if(this.value == 1){
        $('select[name="name"]').toggle();
    }
    else if(this.value == 2){
        $('select[name="class"]').toggle();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Z6Upj/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$(function(){
    $("select[name='option']").change(function(e){
        if ($(this).val() == "1")
            $("select[name='name']").show();
    });
});
```