# How to update a dropdown select based on the value of another dropdown select from seperate Rails models

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, database

I am creating a form that will send out emails in Rails 4.2.1. At the bottom of the form, the user will select the type of email recipients from 3 dropdown selects. The user must fill out the first dropdown, but the other two dropdowns are optional, more specific recipient groups. The first dropdown pulls options from Model A, the second from Model B, and the third from Model C. Model A has_many Model B records, and Model B has_many Model C records. How can I update the next dropdown with information from a model query based on previous input, without refreshing or submitting the form?

TL;DR [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973319/how-to-display-a-dropdown-select-based-on-the-value-of-other-dropdown-select), but getting data from a Rails model.

Model in example here:

```
# contains groupings of recipients
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_bs
end

# contains a smaller, more specific grouping of recipients
class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_cs
end

# even more specific groups of recipients
class ModelC < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: where is the js in all of this? :)

Comment: I feel that view will need to use JS in order to tell Rails that information needs to be pulled @Jony-Y

Answer (score 1):

So knowing you have 3 models:

- Model A
- Model B
- Model C

And supposing you have created 3 dropdowns:

```
<%= select_tag :modelA, options_for_select(@modelA.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, selected: params[:modelA]), prompt: "Select modelA", class: "form-control", id: "modelA-select" %>

<%= select_tag :modelB, options_for_select(@modelB.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, selected: params[:modelB]), prompt: "Select modelB", class: "form-control", id: "modelB-select" %>

<%= select_tag :modelC, options_for_select(@modelC.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, selected: params[:modelC]), prompt: "Select modelC", class: "form-control", id: "modelC-select" %>
```

> STEP 1: On the controller you should add:

```
   @modelA = ModelA.all
   @modelB = []
   @modelC = []
```

> STEP 2: Client sends a request to server and then receives the response then builds the dropdown `modelB` and `modelC`.

```
$(document).on("change", "#modelA-select", function(){
  var modelA = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: _YOUR_URL_,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {modelA: modelA},
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      var modelB = response["modelB"];
      $("#modelB-select").empty();

      $("#modelB-select").append('<option>Select modelB</option>');
      for(var i=0; i< modelB.length; i++){
        $("#modelB-select").append('<option value="' + modelB[i]["id"] + '">' + modelB[i]["name"] + '</option>');
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("change", "#modelB-select", function(){
  var modelB = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: _YOUR_URL_,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {modelB: modelB},
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      var modelC = response["modelC"];
      $("#modelC-select").empty();

      $("#modelC-select").append('<option>Select modelC</option>');
      for(var i=0; i< modelC.length; i++){
        $("#modelC-select").append('<option value="' + modelC[i]["id"] + '">' + modelC[i]["name"] + '</option>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

> STEP 3: Server receives the request, then calculates and sends the results to clients.

```
if params[:modelA].present?
  @modelB = ModelA.find(params[:modelA]).modelB
end
if request.xhr?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      render json: {modelB: @modelB}
    }
  end
end

if params[:modelB].present?
  @modelC = ModelB.find(params[:modelB]).modelC
end
if request.xhr?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      render json: {modelC: @modelC}
    }
  end
end
```

Just a disclaimer here is a reference link if you need more [information](https://viblo.asia/p/sample-dropdown-ajax-with-rails-oOVlYEkal8W)